# Java Generics: <?> vs capture<?>

Tags: java, unit-testing, generics, mockito

I'm trying to mock `ScheduledExecutorService` and I'm having trouble with generics.

Here's a snippet:

```
ScheduledFuture<?> future = mock(ScheduledFuture.class);

ScheduledExecutorService scheduledExecutorService = 
Mockito.mock(ScheduledExecutorService.class);

when(scheduledExecutorService.schedule(Mockito.any(Runnable.class), anyLong(), any(TimeUnit.class))).thenReturn(future);
```

This does not compile with the following error:

```
Error:(20, 109) java: no suitable method found for 
  thenReturn(java.util.concurrent.ScheduledFuture<capture#1 of ?>)
method org.mockito.stubbing.OngoingStubbing.thenReturn(java.util.concurrent.ScheduledFuture<capture#2 of ?>) is not applicable
  (argument mismatch; java.util.concurrent.ScheduledFuture<capture#1 of ?> cannot be converted to java.util.concurrent.ScheduledFuture<capture#2 of ?>)
method org.mockito.stubbing.OngoingStubbing.thenReturn(java.util.concurrent.ScheduledFuture<capture#2 of ?>,java.util.concurrent.ScheduledFuture<capture#2 of ?>...) is not applicable
  (argument mismatch; java.util.concurrent.ScheduledFuture<capture#1 of ?> cannot be converted to java.util.concurrent.ScheduledFuture<capture#2 of ?>)
```

If I declare `ScheduledFuture` without generics, it compiles with a warning.

```
 ScheduledFuture future
```

Is there any way to this in the correctly? I mean, is there any wildcard I can use such that this compiles without warnings?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following works type-correctly:

```
<T> ScheduledFuture<?> thenReturnMockFuture(
    OngoingStubbing<ScheduledFuture<T>> stubbing) {
  // Declare a local abstract class, so that future is type-correct.
  abstract class ScheduledFutureT implements ScheduledFuture<T> {}
  ScheduledFuture<T> future = mock(ScheduledFutureT.class);

  stubbing.thenReturn(future);
  return future;
}
```

Then call like:

```
ScheduledExecutorService scheduledExecutorService = 
    mock(ScheduledExecutorService.class);

ScheduledFuture<?> future = 
    thenReturnMockFuture(
        when(scheduledExecutorService.schedule(...)));
```

---

I think you could also do (without the method, but with the abstract local class):

```
ScheduledFuture<?> future = mock(ScheduledFutureT.class);
doReturn(future).when(scheduledExecutorService).schedule(...);
```

Noting [the caveat](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.11.0/org/mockito/Mockito.html#doReturn-java.lang.Object-) that `doReturn` isn't type-safe, so you've just got to make sure you're invoking a method which does return a `ScheduledFuture<?>`.

Answer (score 4):

The wildcard bound in the `ScheduledFuture` causes problems for type inference. Do you *need* to declare `future` as `ScheduledFuture<?>`?

If not then the following will work:

```
ScheduledFuture future = Mockito.mock(ScheduledFuture.class);

ScheduledExecutorService scheduledExecutorService =
        Mockito.mock(ScheduledExecutorService.class);

Mockito.when(scheduledExecutorService.schedule(Mockito.any(Runnable.class), Mockito.anyLong(), Mockito.any(TimeUnit.class))).thenReturn(future);
```

If you do need to declare `future` as `ScheduledFuture<?>` then the following will work because `doReturn()` is not type-safe:

```
ScheduledFuture<?> future = Mockito.mock(ScheduledFuture.class);

ScheduledExecutorService scheduledExecutorService =
        Mockito.mock(ScheduledExecutorService.class);

Mockito.doReturn(future).when(scheduledExecutorService).schedule(Mockito.any(Runnable.class), Mockito.anyLong(), Mockito.any(TimeUnit.class));
```